# Eigenspace decomposition for semisimple module

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, modules

Let's start with a prime $p$ and a group $\Delta$ of order prime to $p$. Let $M$ be a finite $\mathbb{F}_p[\Delta]$-module of order a power of $p$. I want to find a decomposition into eigenspaces according to the action of $\Delta$ on $M$. 
I know that it is easy to find such a decomposition as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules into cyclic modules (as in the theorem of finitely generated abelian groups), however, I'm having trouble showing that those cyclic modules are invariant under the action of $\Delta$.

I know that $M$ is semisimple, but is the non-canonical decomposition of $M$ into simple $\Delta$-modules invariant under the action of $\Delta$?

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Ok, Maschke's theorem gives an decomposition of $M$ into simple $\mathbb{F}_p[\Delta]$-modules which are in fact invariant under the action of $\Delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maschke's Theorem is the key fact here. For the detailed answer, look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474304/finite-delta-module-of-p-power-order)